# Computing ROC curve to verify the quality of segmentation algorithm

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

1) Let's say I have a set of 100 images, from which I manually extracted the foreground and the background (ground truth).

2) Now I have a segmentation algorithm algorithm which I apply to the previous dataset. The results depend on several algorithm parameters (let's assume I do color segmentation, so the results depend on different color space thresholds in use). The result of the segmentation is a binary mask.

3) So for each of the 100 images I have a ground truth and one prediction. I can easily compute the confusion matrix per image or the final confusion matrix for all the images.

My question: How can I compute the ROC curve?

Ideas:

a) I am thinking to have one ROC curve for each parameter of the algorithm. So I keep N-1 parameters constant  and I vary the other in a normalized scale [0,1]. So for every change in [0,1] I need to re-run the segmentation for all images and compute the TPR and FPR which is a point in the ROC curve. But in this approach I could never evaluate the classifier for all parameters at the same time.

b) Maybe the Roc curve is not the ideal evaluation metric for this case and I have to use something else eg F1 score.

This is a well known [tutorial on ROC curves](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2003/HPL-2003-4.pdf) but in my case I can't compute those scores shown in Figure 3 (they seem to be a metric that shows how confident you are for your classification result, if I understood correctly).

Comment: You could turn each of the confusion matrices into a 0/1 variable and build a ROC with these. Like if your accuracy for a given image is over 0.5, then mark that image as 1: "classified correctly", otherwise as 0.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a similarity measure between different segmantations. I think, this cannot be defined in general but strongly depends on what is important to you (size, shape, area, number of segments, ..). But you opted for the confusion and that is a good compromise of all I think.

Second there are alternatives to ROC (receiver operating characteristic) curves like the precision-recall curve or same ratios but I think they all want to display the type I and type II errors. I think ROC is fine too.

Third there are multiple parameters in your segmentation algorithm. So what to do about them?

I propose you compute all possible combinations and for each false positive rate (FPR) you then display the maximal true positive rate (TPR) that you obtain for any parameter set. In short: just take the best (and memorize the parameters).

Then when you display this ROC curve, for each FPR, you know which parameter set was the best and you also obtain a dependency of these parameter sets on the FPR. This means there is a corresponding curve through the parameter space were the TPR is maximal for each FPR.